# How can I insert automatically specific day and specific timing in MySQL Insert query

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, codeigniter

In MySQL database, there is one table we have to check whether data exist or not today. If the data does not exist after 30 minutes, we have to insert a specific data automatically without any actions. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to perform an action to get result? How are you ever going to do something without an action

Comment: Write script and apply cron job to that script, cron jon will be for every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make a Php script that checks the database. And make it run on specific times by using a cron job (if on linux). Most hosting providers have this option. Otherwise it is possible to get the cron via a package manager for php.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has it's own Event Scheduler, seems reasonable that you would use that to execute your job on a schedule.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html

You should be able to schedule your check and if need be insert 30 mins after a table interaction using a trigger or you could just have a job that runs every 30 mins forever.